# How to construct an f-Timer

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I am trying to costruct an $f$-timer for the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}: x\mapsto \lfloor cx^2\log x\rfloor$ for a proper constant $c>0$; so I need a TM that for every input of lenght $x$, the computation finished in time $cx^2\log x$. How can I approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

PS: my definition of an $f$-timer: is a TM of alphabet $A\supseteq\{0,1\}$ such that for every $w\in \{0,1\}^*$ the computation of input $w$ finished in $f(|w|)$ steps.